# ASP.Net Core 2.1 Web Api 2 And Active Directory Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

I am currently developing `Web Api 2 application` on `ASP.Net Core 2.1` for Group of organizations, and they all have own `Active Directory Domain services`.

I want to check credentials from `ASP.Net Core 2.1 Web Api 2` on a `domain`, that will be specified by user. 
My aim is to have one function that connects to specified active directory service and checks credentials.

Solution will be more valuable if it gets information about user from `active directory`, so I could fill some fields automatically in database

Comment: Will Windows Authentication (built into IIS) not work for you?

Comment: IIS builtin authentication would work if I had 1 domain, but I have multiple. 

Actually answer of Pelice is quite simple and very close to what I need, I have to test it first and if everything will go well, I will implement it into my code.

Comment: Are the domains in the same AD forest? Or do they have a trust between them? Windows Authentication only won't work if there is no trust between the domains.

Comment: I used Pelice's answer and it was okay, exactly what I needed, everything else I built myself, like having several domains in database as patterns to connect and stuff.. Anyways, thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the same for my projects. I've used the Novell library (also works under linux) Novell.Directory.Ldap

Here the documentation: https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/?page=/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/cnet/data/bovumfi.html

to check user credential i've write this code:

```
using (LdapConnection testConn = new LdapConnection() { SecureSocketLayer = _useSSL })
{
    try {
        //Connect function will create a socket connection to the server - Port 389 for insecure and 3269 for secure   
        testConn.Connect(_serverName, _serverPort);

        //Bind function with null user dn and password value will perform anonymous bind to LDAP server 
        testConn.Bind(user.DistinguishedName, password);

        var res = testConn.Bound;
        return res;
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Console.WriteLine($"Authenticate: {ex.Message}");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

If you had it in your practice, can it be used for something else except validation? Like grabbing data about specific user.

Comment: I just opened documentation and everything is clear there.